# How can I automatically generate a new input field when a certain input field is navigated to?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Inspired by the [Chrome Postman extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm), I want to implement a multi-field form section by automatically adding a new input field when a certain field is navigated to, and give focus to the new field. The below screenshot shows how this works in Postman; the down-most row contains a couple of inputs that, when navigated to, results in a new row being added above it, which can be typed into.

[image: Postman]

How can I achieve this behaviour in JavaScript/jQuery? To simplify matters, I need only one input field per row. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/zRrAh/) that should serve as a starting point for a solution.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="last-row">
  <input name="multifield" placeholder="Value"></input>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Having an id named `last-row` is not a good idea since the last row will change. Use a class instead and then use the `:last` selector in jQuery to get the last one.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Are you sure it changes, considering that new rows are *prepended* to #last-row?

Comment: No, not if it prepends. But that would be the wrong day to do it imo.

Comment: Wrong way* (obviously) ... Can't edit my comment! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See how I'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/jCMc8/8/

html:

```
<section>
    <div id="initRow">
        <input name="multifield" placeholder="Value">
    </div>
</section>​
```

javascript:

```
function addRow(section, initRow) {
    var newRow = initRow.clone().removeAttr('id').addClass('new').insertBefore(initRow),
        deleteRow = $('<a class="rowDelete"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZSoHl.png"></a>');

    newRow
        .append(deleteRow)
        .on('click', 'a.rowDelete', function() {
            removeRow(newRow);
        })
        .slideDown(300, function() {
            $(this)
                .find('input').focus();
        })
}

function removeRow(newRow) {
    newRow
        .slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this)
                .next('div:not(#initRow)')
                    .find('input').focus()
                    .end()
                .end()
                .remove();
        });
}

$(function () {
    var initRow = $('#initRow'),
        section = initRow.parent('section');

    initRow.on('focus', 'input', function() {
        addRow(section, initRow);
    });
});
```

​
​

Comment: This is pretty neat, thanks. However, I'd prefer that the new field be inserted right above the downmost row, so that one can create the next row just by tabbing once to the downmost row.

Comment: Works like expected now by using insertBefore();

Comment: I like that you lay out the rows without `<table>`; while I'm not a Web guru, this is the closest to what I'd do.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="item">
            <td><input name="multifield" placeholder="Value" /></td>
            <td><i class="icon delete"></i></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="item inactive">
            <td><input name="multifield" placeholder="Value" /></td>
            <td><i class="icon delete"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("table")
    .on("click focus", ".item.inactive", function(e) {
        var curRow = $(this);
        curRow.clone().appendTo("table tbody");
        curRow.removeClass("inactive").find("input:first").focus();
    })
    .on("click", ".icon.delete", function(e) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/Y8Vh9/).

Comment: It's worth noting that your testcase differs in that it doesn't add a new field if you *navigate* to the downmost ("inactive") field (e.g., by tab'ing to it), but only if you click it. I think I prefer that it react to any navigation to the field.

Comment: @aknuds1 There. Just had to add `focus` to the event listener ;)

Comment: Btw, how did you get that nifty "x" character?

Comment: Is it any faster to select ".item.inactive" for each focus event than to locate the last row once and just prepend to it?

Comment: @aknuds1 Look at the CSS for the X (it's in the pseudo-element). Regarding performance, it's of little concern here. What's important is to have an easy way to handle the dynamic nature of the form, and delegated event handlers do that just fine.

Comment: It is semantically incorrect to use tables in this case. And please do not use the i-tag for icons... ;)

Comment: @griffla I noticed the same :)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I mean, what kind of character is that X? How do you type it in? Yeah I know, I'm not very 1337 :)

Comment: @griffla Why is it semantically incorrect? Because there is only one input? What if there are multiple ones? This testcase is limited to one field for simplicity.

Comment: @griffla It's a form that takes tabular data as an input, so I would argue otherwise. Regarding `i` for icons, sure it's not best practice (regarding to specs), but it's a widely known and used method (bootstrap for example) and is both short and simple.

Comment: @JesperKarsrud It's always one question "is it tabular data?". In my opinion the data stored in the sections the thread starter presented is not tabular. I leave it up to you now to start discussing about the definition of tabular data ;)

Comment: @griffla If its debatable whether it's tabular data or not, then it's also debatable if it's semantically correct or not. I used tables since I regard the input as tabular data, based on the input names and the arrangement of the elements (he even calls it the last row). It makes no sense to simulate table behavior with divs just because you don't consider it tabular data.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I don't think having rows intrinsically implies there be a table, consider for instance Twitter Bootstrap's grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution that seems to work so far, but I'm interested in hearing from others as to whether it is a good one. What I do is catch the focus event for the last input field, add a new row and give focus to the input field within that row. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/VeP8e/) for working code.

HTML:

```
<div id="last-row">
    <input name="multifield" placeholder="Value">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var lastRow = $('#last-row');
var lastInput = lastRow.find('input');

function addRow() {
    var newRow = $('<div><input name="multifield" placeholder="Value"><a class="row-delete"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZSoHl.png" /></a></div>');
    var newInput = newRow.find('input');
    lastRow.before(newRow);
    newInput.focus();

    var newDelete = newRow.find('a');
    newDelete.click(function() {
        newRow.remove();
    });
}

lastInput.focus(function() {
    addRow();
});
```

Comment: Use `lastRow.find('input')` instead of building a new selector with `lastRow.selector`. It's easier to read and will perform better.

Comment: Also, in this case you'd be better off using string concatenation for the generated HTML, since working with DOM elements is much slower. The delete button can be a delegated event on the container as well.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall Does the edited code look better? Not sure about the delegated event bit.